# Find zero byte files

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting

I'm looking for a modern (though not PowerShell) script to help me find zero byte files newer than say, 12 hours. The BAT scripts I'm finding on the web aren't working well. Server is Windows 2003 and I have tens of millions of directories to recurse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're looking for:

```
FOR /R c:\ %I in (*) do @echo %~dpznxI | find "0 c:" >> fileSizedump.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %a in ('type fileSizedump.txt') DO if "%a"=="0 c" echo %a:%b >> fileSizeZero.txt
```

The first command dumps all files that have a 0 at the end of the file size and put it into the fileSizedump.txt file. The second one will weed out only the ones that have 0 for the file size and put those into the file fileSizeZero.txt.